# How to create a perspective button?

Tags: css

I have created a button with perspective view, but the text inside it also rotate with it. How can I get the text show normal. Is there any fault in my code.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
.container {
    padding: 25px;
    border: solid 1px #bebebe;
    perspective: 200px;
    -webkit-perspective:200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

.box {
   display: table;
   background-color: red;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,145deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,145deg); 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? That would make things easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, just need to rotate the text. So if you add a rotation transform effect in it then it will fixed.

```
a {
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,145deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,145deg); 
}
```

[HERE IS A PEN WITH YOUR CODE CHECK THIS](http://codepen.io/palashbasak/pen/xbQYWd)